# html Forms inside reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I used the (almost) exact syntax for creating an html form in react:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return 
         <div>
           <section>
            <form action="http://localhost:9203/ask">
              Text: <input type="text" name="text" value="Text"/> <br/>
              Focus:  <input type="text" name="focus" value="Focus"/> <br/><br/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
          </section>
        </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/9xLa3eLp/

The problem is that in the result, I am not able to edit the forms. Any idea where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by edit the form ? Also show us what result you see and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Like you can't write anything in the forms. Naturally, you expect to be able to write in the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `defaultValue` and not `value`.

If you use value the component becomes a [`controlled component`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and the value cannot be altered. Since you need an [`uncontrolled component`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components) and the input's value should be editable you have to use `defaultValue`.

```
<form action="http://localhost:9203/ask">
   Text: <input type="text" name="text" defaultValue="Text"/> <br/>
   Focus:  <input type="text" name="focus" defaultValue="Focus"/> <br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```